# How do i expand the following macro registers for the ATmega324PB microcontroller?

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller

I am currently learning embedded and i have the following exercise:

Expand the following macro registers:

```
SFR_B_N(0x25,  TCCR2, FOC2, WGM20, COM21, COM20, WGM21, CS22, CS21, CS20)
SFR_B_N(0x08, PORTC,PORTC7,PORTC6,PORTC5,PORTC4,PORTC3,PORTC2,PORTC1,PORTC0)                    
SFR_B_N(0x07, DDRC, DDRC7, DDRC6, DDRC5, DDRC4, DDRC3, DDRC2, DDRC1, DDRC0)                 
SFR_B_N(0x06, PINC, PINC7, PINC6, PINC5, PINC4, PINC3, PINC2, PINC1, PINC0)
```

I did the first example but i'm not sure how to proceed with the other ones

```
SFR_B_N(0x25,  TCCR2, FOC2, WGM20, COM21, COM20, WGM21, CS22, CS21, CS20)
  Expands to:
   __io union { 
               unsigned char TCCR2; 
              struct { 
                       unsigned char TCCR2_Bit0:1, 
                                     TCCR2_Bit1:1, 
                                     TCCR2_Bit2:1, 
                                     TCCR2_Bit3:1, 
                                     TCCR2_Bit4:1, 
                                     TCCR2_Bit5:1, 
                                     TCCR2_Bit6:1, 
                                     TCCR2_Bit7:1; 
                     }; 
               struct { 
                    unsigned char TCCR2_CS20:1, 
                                  TCCR2_CS21:1, 
                                  TCCR2_CS22:1, 
                                  TCCR2_WGM21:1, 
                                  TCCR2_COM20:1, 
                                  TCCR2_COM21:1, 
                                  TCCR2_WGM20:1, 
                                  TCCR2_FOC2:1; 
                      }; 
              } @ 0x25;
```

Comment: What's `SFR_B_N`? Every good IDE does what you want on mouseover.

Comment: Comment out includes and then do `gcc -E`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and what it is. As a starter, it is not a homework solution service. ;-) You need to show some effort on your own, please [edit] your question to add it.

Comment: Thanks for the addition. -- Just do the same with the other ones. Sometimes you need to do boring repetitive work to learn. -- Do you understand what the expanded code _means_? If not, post a new question _after_ trying to find the answer yourself.